# Angular scope $watch without listener

Tags: angularjs, watch

I have seen a code today which was registering a watcher as follows:

`scope.$watch(function() {
    //some code which is not relevant in current context
});`

Angular documentation specifies $watch method as

`$watch(watchExpression, listener, [objectEquality]);`

so what can be the usage of watcher without listener

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
scope.$watch(function() {
    //some code which is not relevant in current context
});
```

is a pattern that can be used to run code once per digest.  It is equivalent to:

```
scope.$watch(function(){
}, undefined);
```

From the [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope):

> If you want to be notified whenever $digest is called, you can
>   register a watchExpression function with no listener. (Since
>   watchExpression can execute multiple times per $digest cycle when a
>   change is detected, be prepared for multiple calls to your listener.)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>You dont *need* the expression</strike> You can use a function to return which var to watch, rather than specifying it in a string, example:

```
$scope.myVar = true;

$scope.$watch(function() {
    return $scope.myVar
}, function(newValue, oldValue) {

});
```

Comment: @SurenAznauryan -- So when did it get executed?

Comment: @SurenAznauryan - Yeah... so verify that the code is running first, then determine when it's running (console.log or debugger)